# What's the best way to save a one-to-many relationship in Linq2Sql?

Tags: linq-to-sql, one-to-many

I'm trying to figure out the best way to save a simple one-to-many relationship in Linq2Sql.

Lets assume we have the following POCO model (pseduo code btw):

*Person has zero to many Vechicles.*

```
class Person
{
    IList<Vehicle> Vehicle;
}

class Vehicle
{
    string Name;
    string Colour;
}
```

Now, when i save a Person, i pass that poco object to the repository code (which happens to be L2S). I can save the person object fine. I usually do this.

```
using (Db db = new Db())
{
    var newPerson = db.People.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id == person.Id) ?? new SqlContext.Person();
    // Left to right stuff.
    newPerson.Name = person.Name;
    newPerson.Age = person.Age;

    if (newPerson.Id <= 0)
        db.People.InsertOnSubmit(newPerson);
    db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

i'm not sure where and how i should handle the list of vehicles the person might have? any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
using (Db db = new Db())
{
    var newPerson = db.People.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id == person.Id) ?? new SqlContext.Person();
    // Left to right stuff.
    newPerson.Name = person.Name;
    newPerson.Age = person.Age;

    // add vehicles.
    Vehicle firstV = new Vehicle();
    firstV.Name = "some name";
    firstV.Person = newPerson; // need to do this to set the person Id on the vehicle.
    newPerson.Vehicle.Add(firstV);
    // now when you save the Person it should save the Vehicle list 
    // if you set Cascade save update on the list. (not sure how to do that in L2S

    if (newPerson.Id <= 0)
        db.People.InsertOnSubmit(newPerson);
    db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Now you may choose to construct the list of vehicles at another level , with the data that's coming from the interface.

But you need to remember that it's not enough to add the Vehicle to the list on the Person object , you also need to set the vehicles Person property to the person that has the vehicles.

<strike>**Observation** I'm not sure about this but when you do *db.People.SingleOrDefault* you might be loading the whole People table in memory . That's not something you want to do.</strike> Corrected by Slace in the comments.

Comment: SingleOrDefault is used when you are providing a query which can only return 1 result (ie, ID comparisons). It lazy-loads like all L2Q ops, as it's done via IQueryable<T>

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is ensure that there are the appropriate relationships set up within the database.

If your Vehicle table has a PersonId and there is a foreign key between them when you add them to the DBML Linq to SQL will detect that there is a relationship between them and create a `Table<T>` representation of the relationship.

Comment: Slace, if u noticed i am using POCO objects ... so i need to somehow generate the L2S objects and populate their data and then L2S needs to figure out if it inserts/updates/deletes ... and i wasn't too sure about how to do that.

Comment: I'm not familiar with POCO, but somewhere you'll have a DBML so as long as that's generated from a DB with the right relationships you're set

Comment: POCO is Plain old C#/CLR Objects